# how to use required in form_validation in ci?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

Hi when I use required in my rules in ci form_validation, I know the value of this required input post and don't show any message .but this if ($this->form_validation->run()) is always false.

thanks for your help.

my view:

```
   <form>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-2"><label>Name</label></div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-pull-1">
                    <input name="Name" class="form-control" id="Name"
                    value="<?php echo set_value('Name')?>"
                    autocomplete="off"></input> 
                    <?php echo form_error('Name'); ?>
              </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

my controller:

```
public function show_info()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Name', 'Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('required'," please enter %s");
    if ($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)
    {
       echo "false";
    }
    else redirect();
}
```

Comment: show us your code. We can't help with out any sample code

Comment: You do not have any form_open() and form_close(); http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open_multipart

Comment: I have it in my code.

Comment: You have no action or any thing in your form

Comment: Yes I have it and I said the value of my input posted ...

Comment: is your problem i solved

Comment: no I have action in my form and if I don't put required in my rules my record inserted in database.but when I use required I can't insert the record

Answer (score 0):

In your view file, you had wrote **nmae** except **name**

```
 <div class="row">
       <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-2"><label>Name</label></div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-pull-1">
                    <input name="Name" class="form-control" id="Name"
                    value="<?php echo set_value('Name')?>"
                    autocomplete="off"></input> 
                    <?php echo form_error('Name'); ?>
              </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

correct it.

Answer (score 0):

please load again view file after false form_validation

```
public function show_info()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Name', 'Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('required'," please enter %s");
    if ($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)
    {
       echo "false";
       $this->load->view('view_file','',true);    
    }
    else redirect();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I try it and my view_file load again without any error message that I set it.